# iPhone: Display a semi-transparent video on top of a UIView?

Tags: iphone, video, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

is it possible to have semi-transparent video (created with blue-screen) playing on top of a UIView ? I was wondering that in case that's not doable with the MPMoviePlayerViewController  it might be by using OpenGL ES and a video texture ?

Thank you in advance,

F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using the ffmpeg library. Here is the link, where you can download a very good example  [link](http://www.codza.com/extracting-frames-from-movies-on-iphone)

Then you just have to set the alpha property to the UIImageView. But i'm not sure about performance, try :)

Comment: Oh that's smart. Yes, I hope iPhone 4's processing power will be enough to cope with it. Thank you Max!

Comment: I tried your solution, only when setting the alpha property the whole ImageView has transparency. nosuic's case is with a blue-screen, then a part of the view needs to have transparency (the blue part). Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: You can substitute blue pixels with transparent ones in runtime and then apply that image to the image view.

Comment: ffmpeg license with the iTunes store is a murky legal situation, look around for more info on this before jumping into something.