# Video with GPUImageChromaKeyFilter has tint when played in transparent GPUImageView?

Tags: ios, video, filtering, gpuimage

I have a video with a solid green background, that I am trying to make transparent with GPUImageChromaKeyFilter.

When I have clear colour for the player view, the result is that the video is not really transparent, but tints the background:

[image: Tint on clear]

When I change the background to white, the green background is gone, but obviously the view is not transparent:

[image: No tint on white]

What am I doing wrong?

My code is:

```
let movie = GPUImageMovie(URL: url)

let filter = GPUImageChromaKeyFilter()
filter.setColorToReplaceRed(0, green: 1, blue: 0)
movie.addTarget(filter)

let playerView = GPUImageView()
playerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
playerView.setBackgroundColorRed(0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)

let trinity = (movieFile, filter, playerView)

filter.addTarget(playerView)
movie.startProcessing()
```

I am storing the movie, filter and view to avoid ARC releasing them when scope is exited and I add the view to the correct superview and position it with auto layout.

The video I am using is an h264 video - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1400954/Coin.mp4

Comment: I was able to get it working with GPUImageChromaKeyFilter, it looks like you just need to call setThresholdSensitivity in addition to setColorToReplaceRed and a single call to set backgroundColor prop. No need to use GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter which is more complex and needs 2 inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working. The solution is to use GPUImageChromaKey**Blend**Filter.
It blends two sources by replacing the pixels of the colour specified in setColorToReplaceRed in the first source with the pixels in the second source.

So I made a GPUImagePicture with a transparent UIImage and added the filter as a target to it. You can use a transparent PNG or build an UIImage and fill it with transparent in code (empty UIImage won't work!)

Now everything works beautifully!

[image: Working!]

The code is

```
let filter = GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter()
filter.setColorToReplaceRed(0, green: 1, blue: 0)

let movieFile = GPUImageMovie(URL: url)
movieFile.addTarget(filter)

let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "MTransparent")
let sourcePicture = GPUImagePicture(image: backgroundImage, smoothlyScaleOutput: true)
sourcePicture.addTarget(filter)
sourcePicture.processImage()

let playerView = GPUImageView()
playerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
filter.addTarget(playerView)

movieFile.startProcessing()
```

Comment: I had to make `filter`, `movieFile`, `sourcePicture` class properties to avoid crashes.

Comment: No need to make them class properties, but you have to have a strong reference to them somewhere, so that they are not released when the scope, where you declare them, is exited.

Comment: Got crash issue. 
`"Tried to overrelease a framebuffer, did you forget to call -useNextFrameForImageCapture before using -imageFromCurrentFramebuffer?"`

Comment: I haven't touched that codebase in many years (since 2017!). Probably the GPUImage library has evolved enough that you need to make some other changes