# Desaturate colors in views below a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, colors

Is it possible to set a backgrounds image such that the views drawn below it are desaturated, rather than just darkened or tinted via a normal alpha value.

I do not have the ability to alter the views below, so it must be contained to the UIView or layer.

Thanks!

Comment: could you pls show any sample image of what you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just overlay the view with a screenshot ([How Do I Take a Screen Shot of a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214957/how-do-i-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-uiview)) and desaturate (ios sdk desaturate image).
Then you can display other viewcontroller modally with transparent background to see-through your desaturated image ([iOS: Modal ViewController with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741224/ios-modal-viewcontroller-with-transparent-background)).

Comment: This works in some cases, but what if for example the view behind is animated?

Comment: I was using GPUImage framework to have transparent/blurred objects placed above playing video. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934643/gpuimage-video-with-transparency-over-uiview